# PHP Populating array on the basis of a certain value in the array

Tags: php, arrays

### What I am trying

I am making an event management system using PHP. In this the event may repeat for some days. In cases where event repeats, the array will contain an end date for repeat ie; the end date till which the event should repeat.

```
  array[] = array([0]=>array(
                             [name]=>test1
                             [start]=>2013-06-23 11:00
                             [end]=>2013-06-23 13:00
                             [repeat]=>true
                             [repeat-end]=>2013-06-25)
                  [1]=>array(
                             [name]=>test2
                             [start]=>2013-06-21 14:00
                             [end]=>2013-06-21 16:00
                             [repeat]=>false))
```

### What I require

If an event repeats then the array must populate with all data till the repeat end date and corresponding start and end.
In the above case the event duration is shown as **start** and **end** and repeat end date is shown as **repeat-end**. In this the array should be populated as shown below:

```
 array[] = array([0]=>array(
                             [name]=>test1
                             [start]=>2013-06-23 11:00
                             [end]=>2013-06-23 13:00
                             [repeat]=>true
                             [repeat-end]=>2013-06-25)
                  [1]=>array(
                             [name]=>test2
                             [start]=>2013-06-21 14:00
                             [end]=>2013-06-21 16:00
                             [repeat]=>false
                  [2]=>array(
                             [name]=>test1
                             [start]=>2013-06-24 11:00
                             [end]=>2013-06-24 13:00
                             [repeat]=>true
                             [repeat-end]=>2013-06-25)
                  [3]=>array(
                             [name]=>test1
                             [start]=>2013-06-25 11:00
                             [end]=>2013-06-25 13:00
                             [repeat]=>true
                             [repeat-end]=>2013-06-25)
                  ))
```

### What I tried

I tried using the php DatePeriod functionality here

```
 foreach ($array as $result){
  if($result['repeat == true']){
    $period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime($result['start']),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime($result['repeat-end']), DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);
    $period = iterator_to_array($period);
       }
     }
```

Using this all the dates between the start and repest-end where obtianed and i inserted values foreach dates into the array. But I could not obtain the last start date in the array and end date became complicated when start and end date [not repeat-end] where different.

Comment: Logic dictates that you want a loop that reads like `while(currentDate <= repeatEnd) { addRepeatEvent; increaseCurrentDateByOne; }`. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Jon: I tried using the DatePeriod functionality but it will be not good when the start and end dates of the event are different.

Comment: @Jon: Also I am not able to return values for the last date using php DatePeriod functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this: (probably could be optimized, but i have feel that this works... or if it is not working completely - it is good start:))

```
$array = array(
array(
                            'name'=>'test1',
                            'start'=>'2013-06-23 11:00',
                             'end'=>'2013-06-23 13:00',
                             'repeat'=>true,
                           'repeat-end'=>'2013-06-25'
),

array(
                             'name'=>'test2',
                            'start'=>'2013-06-21 14:00',
                             'end'=>'2013-06-21 16:00',
                            'repeat'=>false
                             )

    );



$final=array();



foreach ($array as $sub) 

{

    if($sub['repeat']==1) 

    {
        //print_r($sub);

        $start_date = $sub['start'];
        $end_date = $sub['repeat-end'];

$begin = new DateTime($sub['start'] );
$end = new DateTime( $sub['repeat-end'] );
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
// echo $dt->format( "Y-m-d H:i" );

 $new_day=$dt->format( "Y-m-d H:i" );
 $new_end= new DateTime($dt->format( "Y-m-d H:i" ));
 $new_end = $new_end->modify( '+2 hours' ); 

  $temp=array();
  $temp['name']=$sub['name'];
  $temp['start']=$new_day;
  $temp['end']=$new_end->format('Y-m-d H:i');
  $temp['repeat']=true;
   $temp['repeat-end']=$end_date;


$final[]=$temp;



    }
    }

}


//print_r($final);
$done=array_merge($array,$final);

$done=array_unique($done,SORT_REGULAR);

print_r($done);
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear it - yes, i guess you will have to change time of repeated event creation, and maybe something more - but here is basic logic. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not adding timestamp to **$result['repeat-end']** element.
The number of days between 2013-01-01:11:00 and 2013-01-02 is less than 1. So you should replace this line in your code:

```
new DateTime($result['repeat-end']);
```

by this one:

```
new DateTime($result['repeat-end'] . " 23:59:59");
```

This code would work for you:

```
foreach ($array as $result){
    if($result['repeat'] === true){
        $date_start = new DateTime($result['start']);
        //Becouse "time start" > "time repeat-end" you need add timestamp
        $date_end = new DateTime($result['repeat-end'] . " 23:59:59");
        $period = new DatePeriod($date_start,
                                 new DateInterval('P1D'),
                                 $date_end,
                                 DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE
        );
        //Adding new tests to the original array
        foreach($period as $dt){
            $result['start'] = $date_start->modify("+1 day")->setTime(11,0)->format('Y-m-d h:i');
            $result['end'] = $date_start->modify("+2hours")->format('Y-m-d h:i');
            $array[] = $result;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it should be useful for you.